# Finalized DVD-R: can it get infected by malware?

Tags: virus, dvd, worm

Can a finalized DVD-R get infected by virus or malware? Normally finalized DVD (not RW) cannot be changed. Can it be safely put into infected PC?

Answer (score 5):

For all practical purposes, you cannot write on a closed DVD .

But if malware can open a DVD for writing (that kind of DVD or variant of malware) then it might possibly infect the DVD, but I really do not think so.

Most DVDs, once completely closed will not be infected.

Any attempt I make to write on a closed DVD will fail.

I think you are very largely safe.

If you are concerned about the computer you are going to use it on, perhaps scan for viruses with that computers AV app.

Answer (score 2):

No, a finalized disc cannot be infected.

First off, a [finalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalize_(optical_discs)) optical disc cannot be written to again.  Finalization is the last step in the writing process and the disc is marked as complete.  DVD authoring software will not allow data to be written.

Additionally, writing to DVDs is not the same as writing to a standard hard drive. You dont copy files to a DVD, it has to be authored in DVD writing software. Once a file is written to a DVD, it cannot be modified.  This means a virus cant spread by infecting a file on a DVD.  This means the only way a virus could be on a optical disc, is for the file to be infected beforehand.  Before someone throws out a "You could do that;" Yes, there was some authoring software that made it appear you were able to write to a disk like a standard drive, as well as multisession writing, but finalizing the disc is still the end of the ability to write.